# Different networks, same APs, different SSIDs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Could you please help me?, i have a customer office where they have 3 different subnets (are 3 different companies inside one), each company has directors and operative people who need to move to the other side of the office and have the same network segment that this user always is part of (its company segment), and so on with the rest of the people, they need to see on the different physical networks, the 3 different SSIDs from the 3 companies, but will be connected only on its company SSID/Network, and additional point is the users are conected via DHCP, so, this makes a bit confused to perform this connection. Could you please guide me to achieve this?, regards!

Answer (score 1):

Some APs (often business/enterprise-class products, or possibly consumer-class products running aftermarket open source firmware distributions like OpenWrt) have the ability to publish multiple SSIDs and attach each SSID to a separate VLAN. So when traffic comes in from a wireless client on a given SSID, the AP forwards it onto the Ethernet but tags it with a VLAN ID specific to the SSID the client had attached to.

So configure your APs to do that, and plug them into trunk ports of VLAN-capable switches.

Comment: Hello Spiff!,  Thanks for your comments, in fact i am doing tests with robust AP´s (Aerohive), i have two APs doing the simulation of two different areas on an Office who has 3 different companies inside one, users should connect with its own network (VLAN) over the greographic area on that office, i have a L3 Switch giving the access to those AP´s, and configured those ports as Trunk allowing the 3 different VLANs, one of these VLANs is the one who has the internet access NAT/DHCP, user wants to have connection to its own network (VLAN) and also go out to the Internet, really headache...

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you haven't configured proper routing between your VLANs.